# Wordpress: I want my PHP to behave differently depending on the viewport's width

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently working on a Wordpress site. In the navbar there is menu "more" containing various sub-menus. If the viewport is equal or above 768px I want this "more" to disappear and instead display the other sub-menus.

This is the code block responsible for the "more" button in functions.php :

```
$more_button_options = apply_filters( 'monstroid2_theme_more_button_options', array(
'more_button_type'             => get_theme_mod( 'more_button_type', monstroid2_theme()->customizer->get_default( 'more_button_type' ) ),
'more_button_text'             => get_theme_mod( 'more_button_text', monstroid2_theme()->customizer->get_default( 'more_button_text' ) ),
'more_button_icon'             => get_theme_mod( 'more_button_icon', monstroid2_theme()->customizer->get_default( 'more_button_icon' ) ),
'more_button_image_url'        => get_theme_mod( 'more_button_image_url', monstroid2_theme()->customizer->get_default( 'more_button_image_url' ) ),
'retina_more_button_image_url' => get_theme_mod( 'retina_more_button_image_url', monstroid2_theme()->customizer->get_default( 'retina_more_button_image_url' ) ),
) );

wp_localize_script( 'monstroid2-theme-script', 'monstroid2', apply_filters(
'monstroid2_theme_script_variables',
array(
'ajaxurl'             => esc_url( admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ),
'labels'              => $labels,
'more_button_options' => $more_button_options,
) ) );
```

So far, my solution was simply to delete this block but it created another problem as the burger icon (which is displayed under 768px) is not clickable anymore and messes up my whole navbar.

I thought about a simple IF/ELSE declaration in functions.php depending on the viewport's width. However PHP is a server based language. I know how to detect the width with Javascript but I can't figure out how to send this information to PHP. I've searched but did'nt find a solution.

Can anyone help?

Comment: This is nothing PHP can help you with. You need to let JS and CSS do that job. (That said, you _could_ get that data from the second request on, by putting it in a cookie on client side, but not for the first, initial request.)

Comment: nope, it's a wordpress. If I write a CSS the functions.php will still have the priority (already tried ;) )

Comment: Um, what? Sorry, I have no idea what your last comment is meant to say.

Comment: Trying to hide this "more" button AND displaying its submenus using classic CSS methods doesn't work.

Comment: I'm getting the impression that you actively fight your theme here. And as I said above, there is literally no way for the _first_ request to know the viewport of the client.

Comment: Of course, there are methods to get around this issue. (One of the simplest is redirecting mobile viewers to a particular domain on first view. Note that this is _not recommended_ anymore.) But they are ridiculously complex, especially if the only problem they should fix is a misbehaving menu button.

Answer (score 1):

There is a fundamental misunderstanding between the front-end and back-end processes of how a webpage is served. PHP (Hypertext preprocessor) runs on the server and generates the HTTP response that is served to the user by the webserver. The HTTP response (HTML, CSS, JS) is parsed by the user's browser where front-end scripts (Javascript) are then run. There is nothing that you can do with PHP based on the users viewport (unless you are using AJAX to hit some endpoint with this information).

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP to work on viewports are too long and kinky process.
Use CSS to hide the elements on > 768px and same for other sizes as well :)

Best is CSS to do this job.